# Issues parsing API response in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm making a request to a REST API endpoint:

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get(<URL>, headers=headers)
```

I get the following when doing a `print json.loads(response.content)`:

```
{'data': [{'reference': '123', 'name': 'example', 'risk': 'LOW', 'status': 'tbd', 'Description': None, 'found': '2021-04-21', 'last_tested': None, 'resolved': '2021-04-29', 'notes': 'legacy', 'clientid': {'clientname': 'xyz'}, 'categoryid': {'category': 'test1'}, 'subcategoryid': {'SubCategory': 'test2'}}]}
```

Is this valid JSON? I am getting errors and it seems to stem from the "[" to the right of "data".
For example, how would I access the 'reference' value, and even the 'category' (nested) value?

Example, doing this:

```
print (json_response["data"]["reference"])
```

Results in:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Yes, it's valid. It wouldn't parse otherwise. But you need to access it based on the actual structure it has.

Comment: `json_response["data"]` is a list containing one dictionary. You're looking for `json_response["data"][0]["reference"]`

Comment: should be data[0]['reference']. since the value of 'data' in that response is a list

Comment: You can use `response.json`, it will parse it automatically for you.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're using Python 2.x. That version has passed end-of-life, you should upgrade to Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it !

```
print(json_response["data"][0]["reference"])
```

Comment: Thanks all. Just tried in @WillianVieira and worked like a charm. Can't believe I didn't see that one, so simple.